# Export path with space in directory name

Tags: shell, quoting, filenames, variable

I have a path `"/third/party/city of las vegas"`

when `cd` the path I use `"/third/party/city of las vegas"`.

In `.profile` file I have exported the path to a variable as follows

```
export clv="/third/party/city of las vegas"
```

when I try to `cd $clv` it is throwing an error. 
How can I export a path which have spaces in the directory name

Comment: Please post the error, Try: `export clv=/third/party/city\ of\ las\ vegas`

Comment: If you visit that dir often, typing `cd "$clv"` is fairly long. You can reduce the time by making an alias instead: `alias goclv='cd /third/party/city\ of\ las\ vegas'` and then just type `goclv` every time you want to go to that dir.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
export clv="/third/party/city of las vegas"
```

Is the same as

```
export clv=/third/party/city\ of\ las\ vegas
```

Either way, you still need to quote the variable.

```
cd "$clv"
```

The shell will break unquoted expansions on whitespace by default. Remembering to quote variables in contexts like this is a more conventional and probably safer practice.

Note that `"one\ two"` (trying to place an escaped space in quotes) will treat the `\` literally.